# How to append a value to the array of command line arguments?

Tags: c++, arrays, command-line-arguments, argv

My application has entry point

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

}
```

I need to extend  `*argv` array to `n+1` and append a value. For example, I need to append `"-app_ver"`.

I'm a newcomer in C++ (with Java background). I know that I can't change array size, so I need any solution (any approach copying array, etc.)

Comment: Why would you want to do it?

Comment: Have you considered pushing all the values into a `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::vector<std::string_view>` and then appending your new value where you want?

Comment: Just allocate an array of `char *` of size `argc + 2`, copy the original `argc` strings over from `argv[]`, then add your extra value and a final `NULL` in the last two elements.

Comment: Sounds like a "XY problem", as in your solution doesn't sound like the correct one to any sensible programming problem. What is the core problem that you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: Yeah, because at first it's a bit difficult to figure out concept of arrays in c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like cbuchart says, you have to create a new array or maybe a vector.
Using vector and string object can be more simple than char* and array.

Exemple :

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<string> list;
    for ( int i = 1 ; i < argc ; i++){
        string tmp (argv[i]);
        list.push_back(tmp); // add all arguments to the vector
    }

    cout << "number of given arguments : " << list.size() << endl;

    list.push_back("-app_ver"); // add one string to the vector

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++){
        cout << list[i] << endl; // acces data of the vector
    }

}
```

Comment: Right, I tried to keep with the original data types since we don't know the use. As I mentioned in another comment, some APIs, such as Qt and [`QCoreApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#QCoreApplication) require the `char**`, which cannot be obtained from the `std::vector<std::string>` directly. Otherwise, the one described here is a dynamic and safe solution.

Answer (score 17):

To duplicate your `argv`, you can use a `std::vector` of pointers to `char`.

```
std::vector<const char*> new_argv(argv, argv + argc);
```

Then add the new element to it:

```
new_argv.push_back("-app_ver");
new_argv.push_back(nullptr); // or NULL if you are using an old compiler
```

Then replace `argv` with the new array:

```
argv = new_argv.data(); // or &new_argv[0] if you are using an old compiler
argc = argc + 1;
```

---

Note: at the end of normal arguments, there should be a null pointer. It's rarely used (though it's required by the Standard); if you are sure your further code doesn't use it, and you only want to add one element to your `argv` array, you can just overwrite the null pointer, and not use any replacement for `argv`. That is, disregard all the above code, and just do this:

```
argv[argc++] = "-app_ver";
```

However, this is dangerous - it will crash if you ever decide to add one more element, and it might crash if some code requires the presence of a null pointer after the last argument.

Comment: This is by far the most expressive and C++-idiomatic way to solve this problem. Minimal allocation that is automatically managed, and it still can be easily used with C APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The argv is fixed-size block of memory. You have to copy whole content (all the pointers) to bigger array in order to extend it. Or just use `std::vector<std::string> args;` and manipulate this variable as it will do it for you.

But to be honest - redesigning your solution could be a good idea - the copying operation might not be necessary. Maybe something like `std::vector<std::string> additional_parameters;` will meet your needs?

Comment: It depends on the use of the program parameters. The use of `std::vector<std::string>` simplifies the copy but some API's require the `char**` (such as the [`QCoreApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#QCoreApplication) in Qt), and which cannot be directly obtained from the vector. If the original `char**` is not required, yours is a nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

You must construct a new array. Here an example:

```
int new_argc = argc + 2;
char** new_argv = new char*[new_argc];
new_argv[argc + 1] = nullptr;
for (int ii = 0; ii < argc; ++ii) {
  new_argv[ii] = argv[ii];
}
new_argv[argc] = new char[strlen("-app_ver") + 1]; // extra char for null-terminated string
strcpy(new_argv[argc], "-app_ver");

// use new_argc and new_argv

delete[] new_argv[argc];
delete[] new_argv;
```

See that I've allocated only the new parameters for the sake of optimization. To create a full copy you'll have to allocate the memory for the previously existing parameters.

Just be careful with those manual memory allocations: delete them when finishing. You only have to delete the ones you've created.

On the other hand, as `argv` and `argc` are usually used in the `main` function it is not a big deal (the memory-leak).

**Remarks**

As I don't know the future use of these new *command line arguments*, this solution tries to keep with the original data types of the `main` function. If it is passed to Boost or Qt, then the `char**` cannot be obtained from more direct options such as when using `std::vector<std::string>`. To start with, `std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char*`, and those pointers are not consecutive in memory.

A safer option (no manual deletes) can be:

```
int new_argc = argc + 1;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char>> new_argv_aux(new_argc); // automatically destroyed
for (int ii = 0; ii < argc; ++ii) {
  new_argv_aux[ii].reset(new char[strlen(argv[ii]) + 1]);
  strcpy(new_argv_aux[ii].get(), argv[ii]);
}
new_argv_aux[argc].reset(new char[strlen("-app_ver") + 1]);
strcpy(new_argv_aux[argc].get(), "-app_ver");

// Now the actual double pointer is extracted from here
std::vector<char*> new_argv(new_argv_aux.size());
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < new_argv_aux.size(); ++ii) {
  new_argv[ii] = new_argv_aux[ii].get(); // soft-reference
} // last element is null from std::unique_ptr constructor

use_here(new_argc, new_argv.data());
```