# Setting arguments for QtWebEngineProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I'm writing an application to launch a kiosk web application using QT and I'm experiencing a very low performance. By using chromium I was able to solve that by adding some command line arguments (being `--disable-gpu-blacklist` one of them).

I believe these arguments can be passed to the QtWebEngineProcess but I can't find the way to do it since it is automatically launched by the Qt application.

So, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Read [Using Command-Line Arguments](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-debugging.html#using-command-line-arguments):

You can pass as an argument through the command line with:

```
your_app --ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

Or add it to argc and argv:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/43373070/6622587
    std::vector<char*> new_argv(argv, argv + argc);
    new_argv.push_back(const_cast<char *>("--ignore-gpu-blacklist"));
    new_argv.push_back(nullptr);
    argv = new_argv.data();
    argc = argc + 1;
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWebEngineView w;
    w.load(QUrl("chrome://gpu"));
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

---

It can also be set through the environment variables:

```
QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ignore-gpu-blacklist" ./your_app
```

or

```cpp
qputenv("QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS", "--ignore-gpu-blacklist");
QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

Comment: @JosuGoñi It's not that my code is adding more arguments but that Qt internally adds arguments

Comment: As I found on this [blog post](https://myprogrammingnotes.com/pass-parameters-chromium-qtwebengine.html), you can also the environment variable before running your application, i.e., `export QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required"`